# Shift rows of date column according to a group category in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, hql

I have these columns with location and dates. I want to shift the date column down within each location and not the entire column using Hive HQL. I've tried to use `LAG()` but there is no support to Hive on it and also `datediff()` but it does not brings me the shifting date, only date differences.

```
Location    Dates
0000076-0   01/01/2020
0000076-0   28/01/2020
0000076-0   28/02/2020
0000076-0   01/04/2020
0000076-0   28/04/2020
0000076-0   28/05/2020
0000076-0   01/07/2020
000478-2    01/01/2020
000478-2    01/02/2020
000478-2    26/02/2020
000478-2    01/04/2020
000478-2    26/04/2020
000478-2    26/05/2020
000478-2    01/07/2020
0005655-3   01/01/2020
0005655-3   07/02/2020
0005655-3   09/03/2020
0005655-3   07/04/2020
0005655-3   07/05/2020
0005655-3   08/06/2020
0005655-3   01/07/2020
0010828-6   01/01/2020
0010828-6   31/01/2020
0010828-6   29/02/2020
0010828-6   01/04/2020
0010828-6   01/05/2020
```

**Desired output**

```
Location    Dates       Dates_shifted_down_per_location
0000076-0   01/01/2020  null
0000076-0   28/01/2020  01/01/2020     
0000076-0   28/02/2020  28/01/2020     
0000076-0   01/04/2020  28/02/2020     
0000076-0   28/04/2020  01/04/2020     
0000076-0   28/05/2020  28/04/2020     
0000076-0   01/07/2020  28/05/2020     
000478-2    01/01/2020  null     
000478-2    01/02/2020  01/01/2020     
000478-2    26/02/2020  01/02/2020     
000478-2    01/04/2020  26/02/2020     
000478-2    26/04/2020  01/04/2020     
000478-2    26/05/2020  26/04/2020     
000478-2    01/07/2020  26/05/2020     
0005655-3   01/01/2020  null     
0005655-3   07/02/2020  01/01/2020     
0005655-3   09/03/2020  07/02/2020     
0005655-3   07/04/2020  09/03/2020     
0005655-3   07/05/2020  07/04/2020     
0005655-3   08/06/2020  07/05/2020     
0005655-3   01/07/2020  08/06/2020     
0010828-6   01/01/2020  null     
0010828-6   31/01/2020  01/01/2020     
0010828-6   29/02/2020  31/01/2020     
0010828-6   01/05/2020  29/02/2020      
0010828-6   01/06/2020  01/05/2020
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hive supports [`lag()`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics#LanguageManualWindowingAndAnalytics-LAGspecifyingalagof3rowsanddefaultvalueof0).  The code you want is:

```
select t.*,
       lag(date) over (partition by location order by date) as prev_date
from t;
```